# Green's theorem details

Tags: greens-theorem

I'm studying Green theorem. My textbook gives me two examples in which I have a few doubts

> 1st example
>
> Imagine the annulus $D=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}: r^2 < x^2 + y^2 < R^2\}$
>
> $F$ the a vector field of class $C^1$ defined in an open set of $\mathbb{R^2}$. D is an almost regular (union of elementary domains) domain. The boundary of the set is $\partial D=\Gamma_1 \cup \Gamma_2$ with $\Gamma_1$ the circle of radius R anticlockwise and $\Gamma_2$ the circle of radius r clockwise, both centered in the origin.
>
> By Green's theorem
>
> $\int\int_D (\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y})dx dy= \int_{\Gamma_1} Pdx + Qdy + \int_{\Gamma_2} Pdx + Qdy$
>
> If F is a conservative field then $\int\int_D (\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y})dx dy= 0$ so $ \int_{\Gamma_1} Pdx + Qdy = - \int_{\Gamma_2} Pdx + Qdy$
>
> If instead we had $\Gamma _1$ and $\Gamma _2$ both clockwise or anticlockwise we would have $ \int_{\Gamma_1} Pdx + Qdy = \int_{\Gamma_2} Pdx + Qdy$

I'm with everything except my last paragraph. How can we conclude that? Is it because in $ \int_{\Gamma_1} Pdx + Qdy = - \int_{\Gamma_2} Pdx + Qdy$ the minus signal is also because $\Gamma _1$ and $\Gamma _2$ have different directions? Also if F is a closed field shouldn't we have $ \int_{\Gamma_1} Pdx + Qdy = \int_{\Gamma_2} Pdx + Qdy = 0$?

> 2nd example
>
> $F$ the a vector field of class $C^1$ defined in $\mathbb{R^2} except \{0,0\}$.
>
> $F(x,y) = (P,Q) = (\frac{-y}{x^2 + y^2}, \frac{x}{x^2 + y^2})$
>
> We immediately conclude that F is a conservative field.
>
> D is an almost regular (union of elementary domains) domain. The boundary of the set is $\partial D=\Gamma \cup C$ with C the circle of radius R anticlockwise and $\Gamma$ other closed line (exterior to C) also anticlockwise, both centered in the origin (it's a similar set to the one in the 1st example but now instead of two circles we have a circle closer to the origin and other closed path less close to the origin)
>
> C can be parameterized as $\gamma (t) = (R\cos t, R \sin t)$ $0<t<2\pi$
>
> By Green's theorem
>
> $\oint _C F d\gamma = \int_0^{2\pi} F(\gamma (t)) \gamma ´(t) dt = 2\pi$
>
> By the conclusions of the first example we have $ \int_{\Gamma} Pdx + Qdy = \int_{C} Pdx + Qdy = 2\pi$
>
> If we had another closed line $\Gamma _2$ limiting a almost regular domain that did not include the origin in the interior then: $\int_{\Gamma} P dx + Q dy = 0$

Ok first of all: why isn't the integral of F in C zero? Is it because F is not defined in the origin (does this mean it's not a $C^1$ class function?). Therefore in any other path that doesn't include the origin that integral must be zero?

Hope my questions are clear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For your first question:

> I'm with everything except my last paragraph. How can we conclude that? Is it because in $ \int_{\Gamma_1} Pdx + Qdy = - \int_{\Gamma_2} Pdx + Qdy$ the minus signal is also because $\Gamma _1$ and $\Gamma _2$ have different directions? Also if F is a closed field shouldn't we have $ \int_{\Gamma_1} Pdx + Qdy = \int_{\Gamma_2} Pdx + Qdy = 0$?

To apply Green's theorem, $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ are oriented as stated (anticlockwise and clockwise respectively; take a look at how you would divide region $D$ into elementary domains to see why this is the case). To make this explicit, write $\Gamma_1^+$ and $\Gamma_2^-$ for the paths *with* these orientations. Now if the integral is $0$, then you have:
$$\int_{\Gamma_1^+} Pdx + Qdy + \int_{\Gamma_2^-} Pdx + Qdy = 0 \iff
\int_{\Gamma_1^+} Pdx + Qdy =- \int_{\Gamma_2^-} Pdx + Qdy$$
But changing the orientation of a path simply changes the sign of the integral, so you also have:
$$\int_{\Gamma_1^+} Pdx + Qdy = \int_{\Gamma_2^+} Pdx + Qdy \quad\mbox{or}\quad \int_{\Gamma_1^-} Pdx + Qdy = \int_{\Gamma_2^-}Pdx + Qdy$$
which means you get a simple equality if you choose the same orientation.

**Note**: I think they mean $F$ is a *conservative field*. You could talk about a *closed path*, but a *closed field* doesn't make sense to me and from the context, I expect they mean $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=0$, which is the case if $F$ is conservative (i.e. the gradient of some function).

---

The second question isn't completely clear to me, is there information missing? Is $D$ as in example 1? Now $\Gamma$ is just *a path* and $\Gamma_2$ is (another?) *line*...? Is anything given about $F$?

Comment: Hi StackTD! About the first question I think I get it now. The only thing I'm still questioning is "if F is a closed field shouldn't we have $ \int_{\Gamma_1} Pdx + Qdy = \int_{\Gamma_2} Pdx + Qdy = 0$"? Shouldn't the integral of a closed field in a closed line be zero? About the second question you're right there is information missing that I already added (hope the question is clear now). Thanks!

Comment: I added a note about question 1, I assume they mean a *conservative field*. I'll take a look at the updated question 2 later.

Comment: Due to *"We immediately conclude that F is a closed field."*, I suppose you use the term *closed field* for what most would call a conservative field.

Comment: Yes! I meant when $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} = \frac {\partial P}{\partial y}$.  I saw the term in my professor notes, I thought it was used but apparently it's not... So yes it's conservative what I mean. I don't understand how this integrals are not zero when F is a conservative field.